# How to print signature of child class when parent class has __call__ defined

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
class Type:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __call__(self):
        if self.name=="Imaginary":
            print(f"{self.real} + {self.img}i")
        if self.name == "Integer":
            print("integer = {self.num}")


class IntegerType(Type):
    def __init__(self,num):
        super().__init__("Integer")
        self.num = num

class ImaginaryType(Type):
    def __init__(self, real, img):
        super().__init__("Imaginary")
        self.real = real
        self.img = img

b = ImaginaryType(2,3)
b()
```

> output :  2 + 3i

for the above `b` object if i use `inspect.signature` to check the signature of the class i see the following.

```
In [30]: from inspect import signature

In [31]: signature(b)
Out[31]: <Signature ()>
```

After going through the code of `inspect.signature`, I understand that it looks if `__call__` has been overrided in a base class. If so, it prints that. But, here, how can i retain signature of the ImaginaryType class? Which is that it takes `real` and `img` arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` itself is a callable that has a signature with no arguments. It's the *class* of `b` that has a signature taking `real` and `img`. So just call `signature` of the `type` of `b` to get the signature for making a new `ImaginaryType`:

```
>>> signature(type(b))
<Signature (real, img)>
```

You'd have to do this to get the `__init__` signature even if no `__call__` was defined anywhere in the class tree; without `__call__`, instances of the class aren't callable, and have no signatures (instead of getting an empty signature, you'd get a `TypeError` trying to call `signature` on an instance that wasn't callable).